# iphone programming adivce

Tags: iphone

Hello I was wondering if there are any methods that would allow me to interact with the iphone users. What I mean is like  UIALERTVIEW of some sorts that will popup and update them with a status. But I don't want to have a fixed status, but one I can change anytime I want, like say if there is a day off, I want to provide a status over the air and when the user opens the app it will show the new message.

Is this even possible?
If there are any other alternatives please list them

Comment: APNS? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be that your app is contacting your website and downloads any message it should show on startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) to send users important updates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are called Push Notifications. They can put small numbers on your app's icon like the email app when you have new emails, or even show you popups when you need it. Start here: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/push-notifications/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use Push notifications .. or build your own notification system by design a function fired when your application launching to contact your website and check if there any new notification .. then you present a pop , view whatever to show the notification.